# Why my Django URL doesn't grab the right way?

Tags: django

I've a problem with `django` url, when I go to:

```
/cars/my_town/my_office/
```

It's ok and view run as expected, `town="my_town"` and `office_name="my_office"`.

When I go to:

```
/car/my_town/my_office/my_var1/
```

I get an error. 
When I print the vars in my views I get:

`town :"my_town/my_office"` and `office_name:"my_var1"`

My view looks like this:

```
def ListingCars(request,town,office_name,var1=None) :
```

My urls:

```
url(r'^cars/(?P<town>[\w|\W ]+)/(?P<office_name>[\w|\W ]+)/$', web_public_views.ListingCars, name='listingvo_cars'),
url(r'^cars/(?P<town>[\w|\W ]+)/(?P<office_name>[\w|\W ]+)/(?P<var1>[\w|\W ]+)/$', web_public_views.ListingCars, name='listingvo_cars_var1'),
```

SOLVE ... it wasn't a resolverurl problem, but a myfault problem ;) i didn't see a "ç" on my tags name url... that cause the problem... thx for help i clean up my regex and sorry

Comment: What error do you get?..

Comment: No error, but the the url decoder grab : town="my_town/my_office" and office_name="my_var1" and var1=None ... it should be :  town="my_town" and office_name="my_office" and var1="my_var1"

Answer (score 1):

`\W` is *not word*, which will match a slash, you can most likely just omit that and use `\w`, although its not clear what your url's should match, if it is slugs then its most likely that you need `[\w-]+`

```
^cars/(?P<town>[\w-]+)/(?P<office_name>[\w-]+)/$
^cars/(?P<town>[\w-]+)/(?P<office_name>[\w-]+)/(?P<var1>[\w-]+)/$
```

What is actually happening is your first regex is matching your url so it never uses the second one, so most likely you could also fix this by switching the order of these urls so the second is first but I wouldn't recommend this.

Comment: I need white space on url variable so i tried [\w\ -] and try : /cars/MY TOWN/MY OFFICE NAME/MY VAR1 and i v got 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8010/cars/MY%20TOWN/MY%20OFFICE/MY%20VAR1I/
Django Version:  1.8.6
Exception Type:  UnicodeDecodeError
Exception Value:  

'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)

Exception Location:  C:\Users\lolo\Envs\python27_django18\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py in __init__, line 59

Comment: @LaurentCaron - You can't have whitespaces in urls, they get turned into `%20` and matching on that would just be plain ugly

Comment: Sayse , may be, but why ? in the doc
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^articles/2003/$', views.special_case_2003),
    url(r'^articles/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/$', views.year_archive),
    url(r'^articles/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/(?P<month>[0-9]{2})/$', views.month_archive),
    url(r'^articles/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/(?P<month>[0-9]{2})/(?P<day>[0-9]{2})/$', views.article_detail),
]

Works good, and i already use this with old django project with no problem... i don't understand what's wrong on this case ;)

Comment: @LaurentCaron - I don't understand what you mean, that doc pattern is just matching 4 and 2 digit numbers which is unrelated to your issue. Its just a web thing to make it easier to parse urls and for usability that you can't use whitespace, Imagine advertising it... "register at www.myurl.com/ people, you will love it!", would you really expect people to add in the `/ people`?

Comment: Thx but it was more easy than that it was my mistake ;) ... ;)